# How to tell Kerberos where to find the root certificate for LDAP with TLS?

Tags: ssl, kerberos, openldap

I run two Debian servers with MIT Kerberos and OpenLDAP backend. I would like to enforce TLS and encrypt replication. So I created and added certificates…

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/ca.crt
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/server1.crt
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/server1.key
```

…and enforced `STARTTLS`

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changeType: modify
add: olcSecurity
olcSecurity: tls=1
```

After some fiddling, I found out that this also applies to IPC (`ldapi`) and all daemons need access to the root certificate. For example `/etc/nslcd.conf`:

```
ssl start_tls
tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/ca.crt
```

and of course `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`:

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/ca.crt
```

Except for Kerberos. I find no option to tell him about the location of the root certificate. I would expect it in `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[dbmodules]
LDAP = {
        db_library              = kldap
        ldap_kdc_dn             = cn=kdc,ou=daemons,dc=example,dc=com
        ldap_kadmind_dn         = cn=adm,ou=daemons,dc=example,dc=com
        ldap_service_password_file = /etc/krb5kdc/service.keyfile
        ldap_servers            = ldapi:///
        ldap_conns_per_server   = 5
}
```

Consequentially, it complains:

```
kadmind: connection with LDAP-server »ldapi:///«
as »cn=adm,ou=daemons,dc=example,dc=com« can not be established: 
Confidentiality required
```

So, how do I tell Kerberos where to find the root certificate?

Comment: perhaps you have to use ldaps:// ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I tried `ldaps://localhost`, but Kerberos can't get a connection because OpenLDP isn't listening on Port 636 (yet). Wouldn't Kerberos still need a certificate? Also, I think `STARTLS` is preferred nowadays?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: Funny, with `SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:///"`, `ldap_servers = ldaps://localhost` and enforced TLS, Kerberos doesn't care about the validity of the certificate. My immediate problem (encryption) seems to be solved, but I still hope to find a cleaner solution. Anyway: Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this part it seems interesting "16.2.1.8. TLSVerifyClient { never | allow | try | demand }"
https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tls.html